# show that the sequence {$b_n$}, where $b_n = ( 1 + \frac {x}{n})^{l+n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, is strictly decreasing.

Tags: real-analysis

suppose that  $x > 0$, $l \in \mathbb{N}$ and $l > x.$ show that the  sequence {$b_n$}, where  $b_n = ( 1 + \frac {x}{n})^{l+n}$  for  $n \in \mathbb{N}$,  is  strictly  decreasing.

My attempts :   i take $b_{n+1} - b_n =  ( 1 + \frac {x}{n+1})^{l+n+1}-   ( 1 + \frac {x}{n})^{l+n}$......as  i don't know  how to proceed  Further

Pliz help me   any Hinst/solution will be appreciated,,

thanks u

Comment: Try considering $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$ instead (it may work).

Comment: im not getting @Suzet..can u elaborate more

Comment: In order to show that a given sequence $(a_n)$ is strictly increasing, you may show that $a_{n+1}-a_n > 0$ for every $n$, or equivalentely (provided you don't divide by $0$) that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>1$ for every $n$. Sometimes, one way is more straightforward than the other. Typically, when you are dealing with sequences involving exponents, the quotient usually simplifies to some extent.

Comment: @Suzet..i got   $\frac {( 1 + \frac {x}{n+1})^{l+n+1}}{( 1 + \frac {x}{n})^{l+n}}  >  1 $ i mean  here $b_n$ is  strictly increasing  which is  contradiction to my statements

Comment: Ah right, sorry, I misread. Well actually, you need to show that this quotient is $<1$.

Comment: It may also be easier to consider $\ln(b_n)$ instead then. If you prove that the sequence $(\ln(b_n))$ is decreasing then you are done. This also helps you manipulate the exponents more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$l>x\,$ , $\,n>0\,$ , $\,\displaystyle (1+\frac{x}{n})^n<e^x\,$ :

$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dn}\ln b_n = \frac{1}{n}\left(\ln \left((1+\frac{x}{n})^n\right)-\frac{x(l+n)}{n+x}\right) < 
\frac{x}{n}\left(1-\frac{n+l}{n+x}\right)<0$

$ \ln b_n $ is strictly decreasing therefore $\, b_n>0\,$ is strictly decreasing too:

$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dn}b_n = b_n \frac{d}{dn}\ln b_n<0$